# Enable Phone Integration OC 2007/OCS Standard

Tags: ms-office-communicator

I have a basic setup OCS Standard setup w/ OC 2007 clients and Altigen for our phone system.

I want to enable Phone integration through OC 2007, but the check box is grayed out.

I have tried:

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/communicationsservertelephony/thread/3d0c9d95-30ed-44f8-9e04-173b5ef73137

RSOP is showing this policy taking place, but I am not actually seeing a new reg key in regedit.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/communicator-help/set-up-your-computer-to-control-your-phone-HP001154833.aspx (even though this is for 2005)

Any ideas? Anything on the server I need to config to allow this?

Thanks!